# How do I remove button selected state when clicked?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have an app in which I have category collection view and in each cell there is a button whose image I need to change when selected. When the button is clicked the selected id is appended and when I press the tick button I go to another screen and it shows me all the data related to that category. When I unselect the category and press the button it still shows me the data of that category which I don't want. Can anyone help me with this problem?

screenshot of my app:

[image: screenshot for my app]

My code that I have tried so far is:

cellforrow method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if selectedBtnIndex == 1{
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CategoryCell1", for: indexPath) as! CategoryCell1

        let dict = categoryData[indexPath.row]

        if let catName = dict.name, catName.count != 0 {
            cell.categoryName.text = catName
        }

        if let catOffersCount = dict.count {

            if catOffersCount == 1 {
              cell.catOfferCount.text = "\(catOffersCount)"+" "+"Offer"
            }else {
                cell.catOfferCount.text = "\(catOffersCount)"+" "+"Offers"
            }
        }

        cell.categoryImage.image = arrCategoryImages[indexPath.row]

        cell.btn_click.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.btn_click.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.click_Category), for: .touchUpInside)

        if selectedIds.contains(categoryData[indexPath.row].ID!) {
            cell.btn_click.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_checked"), for: .normal)
            cell.btn_click.isSelected = true
        }else {
            cell.btn_click.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_unchecked"), for: .normal)
            cell.btn_click.isSelected = false
        }

        return cell
```

Button add target function:

```
@objc func click_Category(sender: UIButton!) {
    if sender.isSelected == true {
        selectedIds.append(categoryData[sender.tag].ID!)
        sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_checked"), for: .normal)
        sender.isSelected = false
    } else {
        selectedIds = selectedIds.filter{ $0 != sender.tag }
        sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_unchecked"), for: .normal)
        sender.isSelected = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is mainly two bugs with the posted code. These logical bugs are in the **click_Category** function. Bugs are:

1.Toggling the UIButton image using ***sender.isSelected*** is not properly handled.
2. First block of "if" statement appends ID's in **selectedIds** array but when again tap on the same UIButton to uncheck it, **selectedIds** array does not remove the unchecked UIButtons ID.

Here is the code snippet for modified **click_Category** function:

```
 @objc func click_Category(sender: UIButton!) {

    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
    if sender.isSelected {
        selectedIds.append(categoryData[sender.tag].ID!)
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "image_checked"), for: .normal)
    }else {
        selectedIds = selectedIds.filter {$0 != categoryData[sender.tag].ID!}//removing the unchecked ID
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "image_unchecked"), for: .normal)
    }

}
```